# Is there a way to use FluentUI Stack component without Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fluent-ui

The examples on FluentUI use the IStackTokens interface to style the elements in the stack. The older props like "gap" are obsolete now. When I try to space out the items like in the example with:

`const stackTokens: IStackTokens = { childrenGap: 5 };`

I get an error saying types can only be used with Typescript.
I could just style the elements normally, but this functionality seems to be built into the stack and I'd like to use it if I can!

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the Typescript parts? As far as I know, if you want it done automatically, you would use a Typescript compiler. But if you are already using a typescript compiler, than there is no reason to remove it.. You could just remove the Typescript code manually. Hopefully, you know what is acceptable in Javascript.

Comment: thanks! I wanted to use the typescript parts without using typescript... but decided I'd just use typescript instead.